# Why doesn't work method of adding a contact to the array?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I add a new contact in the method: `addToBook()`. First I check the fields, if they are not empty, then I create the instance of the class `LocalStorage` and pass the field values and make `JSON` from it.

I want to see the new product in the array and `LocalStorage` but I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'push' of undefined"
```

Help me fix it.

```js
class Contacts {
  constructor() {
    // Storage Array
    this.contacts = [];
  }

  addToBook() {
    let isNull = forms.name.value != '' && forms.phone.value != '' &&
      forms.email.value != '';
    if (isNull) {
      // format the input into a valid JSON structure
      let obj = new LocalStorage(forms.name.value,
        forms.phone.value, forms.email.value);
      this.contacts.push(obj);
      localStorage["addbook"] = JSON.stringify(this.contacts);
      console.log(this.contacts);
    }
    console.log(this.contacts);
  }
}
let contacts = new Contacts();
class Forms {
  constructor() {
    // Blocks
    this.addNewContact = document.getElementById("addNewContact");
    this.registerForm = document.querySelector('.addNewContact-form');
    // Forms
    this.fields = document.forms.register.elements;
    this.name = this.fields[0].value;
    this.phone = this.fields[1].value;
    this.email = this.fields[2].value;
    // Buttons
    this.cancelBtn = document.getElementById("Cancel");
    this.addBtn = document.getElementById("Add");
    this.BookDiv = document.querySelector('.addbook');
    // display the form div
    this.addNewContact.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      this.registerForm.style.display = "block";
      if (this.registerForm.style.display = "block") {
        this.BookDiv.style.display = "none";
      }
    });

    this.cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      this.registerForm.style.display = "none";
      if (this.registerForm.style.display = "none") {
        this.BookDiv.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
    this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", contacts.addToBook);
  }
}
let forms = new Forms();

class LocalStorage {
  constructor(name, phone, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.email = email;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="AddNewContact">
  <button id="addNewContact" type="button">Add new contact</button>
  <i class="fas fa-search "></i>
  <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH BY NAME">
  <button id="ImportData" type="button">Import data to book</button>
</div>
<div class="addNewContact-form">
  <form name="register">
    <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" class="formFields">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label><input type="text" id="phone" class="formFields">
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label><input type="text" id="email" class="formFields">
    <br><br>
    <button id="Add" type="button">Add Now</button><button id="Cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a reference to a function like this:

```
this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", contacts.addToBook);
```

you loose the binding to `this`. Which you depend on when you call `this.contacts.push(obj);` in `addToBook()`

You can hard bind the reference you want `this` to be with:

```
this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", contacts.addToBook.bind(contacts);
```

You could also pass in a function that explicitly calls `addToBook` with the correct context:

```
this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => contacts.addToBook());
```